# Domain that shows another domains subdirectory

Tags: dns, subdomain

Is it possible to have e.g. "domain.com" that shows "domain2.com/dir".

What I mean is, that instead of domain.com just redirecting, I want it to show e.g. "domain2.com/dir/subdir" as "domain.com/subdir"

All this is regarding to a CMS.

What I need is, that my frontend to my CMS is at domain.com. A customer is creating his account with a shorttag. E.g. "domain2.com". Then their unique URL to THEIR frontend is "http://domain.com/domain2.com".

What I need is, that domain2.com can show "http://domain.com/domain2.com" - so that the customers doesn't need to redirect their users to http://domain.com/domain2.com, but can simply just redirect to their own domain - domain2.com

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cPanel you can set up an addon domain that can point to a specific directory.

If you're just using apache you'll need to point the domain to another folder in the vhosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/user/domain.com"
    ServerName domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/user/domain.com/dir"
    ServerName domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hello, Adam. Does this mean, that most hosting providers will give me the chance to set up these things? And what if it is a non-existing subfolder?
E.g. if it is just from the database like this: domain.com/?user=dir
My extra question is: Can domain2.com show to domain.com/?user=dir :)

Comment: Sounds like you might want htaccess url rewriting instead. The vHosts option is for a full second site inside that dir, good for mobile sites and things.<br/> Here's a good guide to get you started http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Adam G: Nope, I want a domain to show the full subdomain. It's for a CMS where each customer should have a "subfolder" for their site - but then they maybe want their own domain, so it is important to make it possible to make that domain show the subfolder/url from where the CMS is located :)

Comment: Could you edit the question to give some more detail? Need a clearer picture of what you're looking for.

Comment: Added some details - hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use http header in your first page(domain2.com/dir/subdir) to redirect to second page
in php this is something like this (in index.php file in subdir):

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Location: http://domain.com/dir');
die();
?>
```